# c isalpha and isdigit while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets

How do I put isalpha and isdigit in a while(1) loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char type[256];
    printf("You can type a number or a word. Type exit to exit! \n");
    printf("Type: ");

    fgets (type, 256, stdin);

    if (isalpha(type[i]))
    {
            printf("Typed text: %s\n", type);
        if((strcmp(type,"exit\n") == 0))
        {
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (isdigit(type[i]))
    {
            printf("Typed number: %s\n", type);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Typed: %s\n", type);
        printf("Its not a letter or number...?!\n");
    }
}
```

I tried adding while(1) at the start at the code and close it at the end of code, but as soon as I enter number or letter the console crashes... Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean with "the console crashes"? Where is `i` declared and how do you initialize it?

Comment: show us the complete code please.

Comment: .exe file crash. I'm learning C so this might not be the best way of doing things.

Comment: Don't use anything you don't understand. The wording of the question just screams [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). While loops are loops with a terminating condition. `[i]` is not valid unless `i` is within bounds etc.

Comment: Your title says while loop but i dont see a while loop anywhere

Comment: @JackWilliams did you read the first sentence?

Comment: @sehe no sorry i missed that but he shouldnt be expecting us to do it for him. He didnt even make an attempt

Comment: variables in c are not automatically initialized, strings in c are zero terminated, strings in c are arrays of chars. these basics you should carefully understand, before jumping to loop; try some beginners tutorials. this is a friendly advise, and yet you are welcome to c world. :)

Comment: More friendly advice - find out how to use a debugger before attempting to develop any more software.  ATM, you don't have the skills to write this kind of code, (ie more complex than 'Hello world!').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not a loop problem, you need to give a value to i , as it is undefined and you get a nice crash. Please replace

```
int i;
```

with

```
int i=0;
```